# String chunking algorithm with natural language context

Tags: c#, string, nlp

I have a arbitrarily large string of text from the user that needs to be split into 10k chunks (potentially adjustable value) and sent off to another system for processing.

- Chunks cannot be longer than 10k (or other arbitrary value)
- Text should be broken with natural language context in mind

  - split on punctuation when possible
  - split on spaces if no punction exists
  - break a word as a last resort

I'm trying not to re-invent the wheel with this, any suggestions before I roll this from scratch?

Using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not handle every case as you need, but it should get you on your way.

```
    public IList<string> ChunkifyText(string bigString, int maxSize, char[] punctuation)
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        string chunk;
        int startIndex = 0;

        while (startIndex < bigString.Length)
        {
            if (startIndex + maxSize + 1 > bigString.Length)
                chunk = bigString.Substring(startIndex);
            else
                chunk = bigString.Substring(startIndex, maxSize);

            int endIndex = chunk.LastIndexOfAny(punctuation);

            if (endIndex < 0)
                endIndex = chunk.LastIndexOf(" ");

            if (endIndex < 0)
                endIndex = Math.Min(maxSize - 1, chunk.Length - 1);

            results.Add(chunk.Substring(0, endIndex + 1));

            startIndex += endIndex + 1;
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: +1 I ended up implementing something similar to this.  Thanks for the code example!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this will probably end up being more difficult than you're expecting (most natural language things), but check out [Sharp Natural Language Parser](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/).

I'm currently using SharpNLP, it works pretty well, but there's always 'gotcha's'.

Let me kow if this isn't what you're looking for.

Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll check that library out.